# Template, why call template function in this way doesn't working?

Tags: c++, templates

I am reading a book (Accelerated C++) and doing exercise from that book trying to learn C++ by myself.

Now I am trying to understand why the following piece of code doesn't working:

```
// analysis.cpp
void write_analysis(ostream& out, const string& name,
                    double analysis(const vector<Student_info>&),
                    const vector<Student_info>& did,
                    const vector<Student_info>& didnt)
{
  out << name << ":median(did) = " << analysis(did) <<
    ", median(didnt)=" << analysis(didnt) << endl;
}

template <double F(Student_info&)>
double generic_analysis(const vector<Student_info>& students)
{
    vector<double> grades;

    transform(students.begin(), students.end(),
          back_inserter(grades), F);
    return median(grades);
}
template<> double generic_analysis<grade_aux>(const vector<Student_info>& students);

double median_analysis(const vector<Student_info>& students)
{
    return generic_analysis<grade_aux>(students);
    // if not using template function, the code will be 
    // as following
    // vector<double> grades;

    // transform(students.begin(), students.end(),
    //           back_inserter(grades), grade_aux);
    // return median(grades);
}
```

analysis.cpp

```
// analysis.h
template <double F(const Student_info&)>
double generic_analysis(const std::vector<Student_info>&);

void write_analysis(std::ostream&, const std::string&,
                    double analysis(const std::vector<Student_info>&),
                    const std::vector<Student_info>&,
                    const std::vector<Student_info>&);

double grade_aux(const Student_info&);

double median_analysis(const std::vector<Student_info>&);
```

analysis.h

```
// main.cpp
int main()
{
  // students who did and didn't do all their homework
  vector<Student_info> did, didnt;

  // read the student records and partition them
  Student_info student;
  while (read(cin, student)) {
    did.push_back(student);
  }

  // do the analyses
  write_analysis(cout, "median", median_analysis, did, didnt);

  return 0;
}
```

main.cpp

```
// grade.cpp 
// compute a student's overall grade from midterm and final exam grades
// and homework grade
double grade(double midterm, double final, double homework)
{
  return 0.2 * midterm + 0.4 * final + 0.4 * homework;
}

double grade_aux(const Student_info& s)
{
  try {
    return grade(s);
  } catch (domain_error) {
    return grade(s.midterm, s.final, 0);
  }
}
```

grade.cpp

and the error message is:

> g++ -Wall *.cpp -o main /tmp/ccbXbVcV.o: In function
>   `median_analysis(std::vector<Student_info,
>   std::allocator<Student_info> > const&)': analysis.cpp:(.text+0x91):
>   undefined reference to`double
>   generic_analysis<&(grade_aux(Student_info
>   const&))>(std::vector >
>   const&)' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Meanwhile, when I put the generic_analysis code declare and definition inside header file,
it will work. Please someone explain why?

**Edit:**
When removed the line:

```
template<> double generic_analysis<average_grade>(const vector<Student_info>& students);
```

I got:

> g++ -Wall *.cpp -o main
>   /tmp/cc3VhXKU.o: In function `median_analysis(std::vector<Student_info, std::allocator<Student_info> > const&)':
>   analysis.cpp:(.text+0x91): undefined reference to`double generic_analysis<&(grade_aux(Student_info const&))>(std::vector > const&)'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

So seems like I need an `Explicit instantiation`. I then added the following line:

```
template double generic_analysis<grade_aux>(const vector<Student_info>&);
```

now the error message are:

> g++ -Wall *.cpp -o main
>
> analysis.cpp: In instantiation of ‘double generic_analysis(const std::vector&) [with double (* F)(const Student_info&) = grade_aux]’:
>
> analysis.cpp:26:72:   instantiated from here
>   analysis.cpp:26:72: error: explicit instantiation of ‘double generic_analysis(const std::vector&) [with double (* F)(const Student_info&) = grade_aux]’ but no definition available [-fpermissive]
>   analysis.cpp: In instantiation of ‘double generic_analysis(const std::vector&) [with double (* F)(const Student_info&) = grade_aux]’:
>
> analysis.cpp:26:72:   instantiated from here
>   analysis.cpp:26:72: error: explicit instantiation of ‘double generic_analysis(const std::vector&) [with double (* F)(const Student_info&) = grade_aux]’ but no definition available [-fpermissive]
>   analysis.cpp: In instantiation of ‘double generic_analysis(const std::vector&) [with double (* F)(const Student_info&) = grade_aux]’:
>
> analysis.cpp:26:72:   instantiated from here
>   analysis.cpp:26:72: error: explicit instantiation of ‘double generic_analysis(const std::vector&) [with double (* F)(const Student_info&) = grade_aux]’ but no definition available [-fpermissive]

Comment: Explicitly instantiating the template is probably more trouble than the result is worth, as given that `generic_analysis` and `grade_aux` live in different TUs trying to instantiate the former with the latter is bound to be painful. I recommend you put the definitions of function templates like `generic_analysis` in headers, as is customary with templates.

Answer (score 2):

You define:

```
template<> double generic_analysis<grade_aux>(const vector<Student_info>& students);
```

Where is the implementation?

If you are trying to *force* instantiation of a function:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp6m.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc16explicit_instantiation.htm

Comment: @pstar No,  once you declared a template function specialization you must implement it.

Comment: Now the questions is how do I implement a template function specialization?

Comment: @pstar just as you would a regular function.  Template provides a generic implementation - specialization handles special cases.  hence the name.

Comment: I am not sure I need specialization at all, please see comments I added in `median_analysis`.

Comment: @pstar remove the specialization and see if you happy

Comment: No, no, remove the `template<> double gener...` line

Answer (score 1):

You declared

```
template<> double generic_analysis<grade_aux>(const vector<Student_info>& students);
```

but didn't define it anywhere. If you really intend on having such an explicit specialization, you'll need to define it (likely not in the header however).

If on the other hand the intent is that the primary template `generic_analysis` be used, then you don't need to declare the above specialization.

Comment: I thought that line is for compiler so it can link template definition and its implementation, otherwise it wouldn't compile. My intention is using `generic_analysis` to handle `median_analysis`

Comment: @pstar I suggest you try without that declaration then.